# How to map an array of map from Firestore to recyclerView?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document in Firestore containing an array (users) containing maps with some data.

```
users[
    {name=Avina, pic=https://profilepic.com/img152}, 
    {name=Avina, pic=https://profilepic.com/img152}
]
```

I have a data class in the app, `User`:

```
data class User(val name: String, val pic: String)
```

So what I need to do is to get the document data then store it in an ArrayList, that supplies it to the RecyclerView adapter.

How can I do that?

[image]

I have followed [this guide](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10), but it results in error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object.
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the content of the "users" array as a list of User objects, then you should simply create a new class that contains that specific list like this:

```
data class UserDoc (
    var users: MutableList<User>? = null
)
```

Now to read the data, you can simply use:

```
val users = document.toObject(UserDoc.class).users
```

I have also written an article on this topic called:

- [How to map an array of objects from Cloud Firestore to a List of objects?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10)